# Google Cloud sql and Google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I did this tutorial https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/developers_guide_java
When I run app locally on my machine, eclipse's console generates error

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.sun.jdbc.odbc)  at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
>     at
>   java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
>     at
>   java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:252)
>     at
>   java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(SecurityManager.java:1512)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:114)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)   at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getCallerClass(DriverManager.java:477)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:576)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)  at
>   org.apache.jsp.guestbook_jsp._jspService(guestbook_jsp.java:64)   at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.access$101(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:23)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet$2.run(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:59)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.service(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:57)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileUtils.serveWelcomeFileAsForward(StaticFileUtils.java:80)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet.maybeServeWelcomeFile(LocalResourceFileServlet.java:254)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet.doGet(LocalResourceFileServlet.java:120)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:363)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)  at
>   org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

but the app is working. Then I deploy my app in gae, and when i enter my app, it's give me error *

> Error: Server Error The server encountered an error and could not
>   complete your request. If the problem persists, please report your
>   problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.

Who can help me?

Comment: Did you follow this instructions: http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/cloudsql.html

Answer (score 3):

When you run locally you need to setup a local MySQL instance. Follow the instructions under the section *Using a Local MySQL Instance During Development*.

Answer (score 1):

As iein valdez notes correctly, you have to create a local MySQL instance for local testing.
The instructions can be found at this link: https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/developers_guide_java#using_the_java_development_server